# Postcondition: this->get_id()==thread::id() in Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

In reading the thread management section of the Boost [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html), I see the following under "Default Constructor":

> **Postconditions:** 
>      `this->get_id()==thread::id()`

I understand that `this->get_id()` returns the current thread's ID, but what does `thread::id()` do? I can't seem to find `thread::id()` in the documentation.

What is the meaning of Postconditions?

I had originally understood Postconditions to be return values, but that understanding doesn't make sense with the default constructor documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thread::id()` is an object of type [`thread::id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) that is constructed with the default constructor. A default-constructed id object does not represent a thread, and all default-constructed id objects compare equal. The short form of that is that the default constructor for a `thread` object creates an object that does not represent a thread of execution.